# Loading Thumbnail of a page Image Attribute in Concrete5

Tags: php, image, attributes, thumbnails, concrete5

I like to load a image attribute and assign a custom thumbnail named `small` (created in `Dashboard > System > Files> Thumbnails`) to the image.

I created a custom image attribute `blogimage` in a template. Loading the image attribute works. Just need to know how to load the custom thumbnail.

```
<?php
    $img = $c->getAttribute('blogimage'); ?>
    <?php if ($img): ?>
    <img src="<?php  echo ($img->getVersion()->getRelativePath()); ?>"/>
<?php endif; ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `blogimage` is the handle of a Image/File attribute, and `$c` is a `Page` instance, the following code

```
$img = $c->getAttribute('blogimage');
```

returns `null` if the page doesn't have a value for that attribute, or a [`Concrete\Core\Entity\File\File`](https://documentation.concrete5.org/api/8.4.0/Concrete/Core/Entity/File/File.html) instance otherwise.

Then

```
$imgVersion = $img->getVersion();
```

returns a [`Concrete\Core\Entity\File\Version`](https://documentation.concrete5.org/api/8.4.0/Concrete/Core/Entity/File/Version.html) instance, which has the [`getThumbnailURL`](https://documentation.concrete5.org/api/8.4.0/Concrete/Core/Entity/File/Version.html#method_getThumbnailURL) method.

So, in order to have the URL of the thumbnail type with handle `small`, you simply have to write this:

```
$img = $c->getAttribute('blogimage');
if ($img !== null) {
    $imgVersion = $img->getVersion();
    $thumbnailURL = $imgVersion->getThumbnailURL('small');
    ?><img src="<?= $thumbnailURL ?>" /><?php
}
```